# How to make SAS not remove the 0 to the left of a number

Tags: date, sas

I'm new to programming in SAS and I'm trying to create my own date format, which would be the name of the month, the year (4 digits) and the day (ALWAYS two digits), the problem is that from 1 to 9 it takes them as 1 single digit, and it would need to be 2 (with the 0 included). in the following way

I have it like this February20221 and I want it like this February202201

What I have done is this:

```
%let m=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()), monname.));
%let y=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()), year));
%let d=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()), day));

%let date= %sysfunc(cat(&m,&y,&d));
```

How could I add this? I have tried with the cat function, with put, input... everything, but it always eliminates the 0 on the right.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proc Format is the right tool to create a custom date format.

Here is what's going on in Proc Format:

- The Picture Statement creates a Picture Format. A Picture Format tells SAS how to display a number (a SAS date is an integer).
- `dtfmt` is the name of the format and the Default Option sets the length.
- The Other Keyword specifies that the format should be applied to all values it encounters.
- %B%Y%0d is a series of *Directives*. Directives specify how a date value should be presented. You can see a full list of directives [here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0n990vq8gxca6n1vnsracr6jp2c.htm#p0eubpiv9ngaocn1uatbigc5swi2).

See if this works for you

```
proc format; 
  picture dtfmt (default=30)
    other = '%B%Y%0d' (datatype=date)
  ;
run;

%let date= %sysfunc(date(), dtfmt.);

%put &date.;
```

This prints:

```
February202201
```

Note: The result may be different based on your [Locale System Option](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/nlsref/n1n9bwctsthuqbn1xgipyw5xwujl.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, I am extremely grateful, the result that I am trying to obtain in the macrovariable would be in Febrero202101 format, with the F in capital letters, how could I change this?

Comment: In your question, you write : "I have it like this February20221 and I want it like this February202201". Do you want February or Febrero ?

Comment: Excuse me, the mistake was mine, I would like to have it in February and if possible, could you explain to me a little what is inside the proc format

Comment: The only problem I have is that I need the first letter of the month to be in uppercase. thank you very much

Comment: I just updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: You can set options locale = English_UnitedStates; before you run the code to ensure a capital F.

Comment: I'm from Spain, I could just put
locale = Spain? thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241617/discussion-between-abel-perez-and-draycut).